# Determine when a Domain Controller was promoted

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain, audit

On Windows Server 2003 standard is there a way to determine when a domain controller was promoted?

This is for an Active Directory 2000 functional domain.

The event logs don't go back far enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have Event Logs, you can check the creation date of the `SYSVOL` directory:

`C:\> dir /T C C:\Windows\SYSVOL`

Also of note is `C:\WINDOWS\Debug\DCPROMO.LOG`

Answer (score 1):

AD has an attribute for DC's that is called `whenCreated` that stores a date/time field.

Comment: I was curious about this attribute. Is it updated when a member server is promoted to a DC?  I ask because, on my DCs, the attribute date/time doesn't match the `dcpromo.log`. Also, all non-DC member servers also have this attribute.

Comment: Good point. It must from be when the Computer entry is created in AD, which (except for the first DC) will not necessarily be when it is promoted.